# Basic question about java bit-wise operation

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Can anyone explain why the first println output 0 and the second println output 2?

```
int count = 1;
System.out.println(count + 1&1);
System.out.println(count += 1&1);
```

Comment: Precedence.........

Comment: For the second case: the value of an assignment is the assigned value. And since `count += 1&1` is just a shorthand for `count = count + (1&1)`, the assigned value is `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple order of evaluation. The first example is equivalent to

```
System.out.println((count + 1) & 1);
```

which is (of course) `System.out.println(2 & 1);` which is `0`.